# Isn't the tag 'tafsir' synonymous to the tag 'tafseer'?

Tags: discussion

We have two tags which sound the same and mean the same.

They are:

- [tafsir](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tafsir)
- [tafseer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tafseer)

They are the same word but just spelt differently as there is no direct spelling of an Arabic word in English.

For example, some people say `assalamu alaykum` and others say `assalaamu alaikum`.

**Question:** Isn't the tag 'tafsir' synonymous to the tag 'tafseer'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. That's why they're marked as synonyms: https://islam.stackexchange.com/tags/tafseer/synonyms

This way, whenever a user tags a question as [tafsir](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tafsir), it'll automatically remap to [tafseer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tafseer), and searching for one will bring up both. This is by design, since both spellings are in common use.

Comment: Perhaps it should be [tafsir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafsir) though (?).